nginx reverse proxy to django app not working in firefox
I have a very simple django app with only one page for testing. I want to use it within a docker compose stack together with nginx as reverse proxy.
Now I have the problem that I cannot reach the django app from Firefox (page gets reset while loading), but in chrome and with curl it works correctly.
Here is the firefox get request when accessing the django app over the reverse proxy:
GET /app/ undefined
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:129.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/129.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/png,image/svg+xml,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Priority: u=0, i
Pragma: no-cache

There is no response, only ns_error_net_reset error message.
I also started the django app and nginx natively without docker, then everything works as expected, the firefox get request looks like this:
GET /app/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:129.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/129.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/png,image/svg+xml,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Priority: u=0, i
Pragma: no-cache

The nginx server config file is already stripped down to the minimum working example:
server {
    listen       80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /app/ {
        proxy_pass   http://web:8000/;
    }
}


I don't know what the problem is in firefox. I use MacOS and Firefox 129.0.2.
So far I have no ideas anymore how to debug this issue and appreciate any help!
Edit:
For completeness, here is the docker compose file:
services:
  web: 
    build:
      context: app
      target: builder
    entrypoint: >
      sh -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn example.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level debug"
    ports: 
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - static:/app/staticfiles
    environment:
      - DEBUG=False
    networks:
    - frontnet
    
  proxy:
    build: proxy
    ports:
      - 9000:80
    depends_on:
      - web
    restart: always
    networks:
    - frontnet
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static

volumes:
  static:

networks:
  frontnet:

The Dockerfile of nginx only copies my local proxy.conf to the container into /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
